# Dynamic scope for oauth-4-laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, oauth-2.0

I would like to incrementally request scopes as necessary throughout my application.

For example, at login, I might need only email and profile.

```
'consumers' => array(
        'Google' => array(
            'client_id'     => 'clientid.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            'client_secret' => 'clientsecret',
            'scope'         => array('email', 'profile'),
        )
    )
```

Later in my application if a user wants to manage their contacts list, I might want to request the scope as:

```
'Google' => array(
                'client_id'     => 'clientid.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                'client_secret' => 'clientsecret',
                'scope'         => array('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/'),
            )
```

Is there an elegant Laravel way to achieve the following without setting/checking a flag variable at the start of this config file?

Answer (score 1):

The generic way to set Laravel-4 config files is

```
Config::set('key', value);
```

For the above this did the trick:

```
Config::set('oauth-4-laravel.consumers.Google.scope', ['https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/']);
```